# Redirect an URL once successful

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

```
import re
DEFAULT_SUCCESS_URL = re.compile(r'^(?P<clientcode>[0-9]{9})/dashboard/')
url(r'^(?P<clientcode>[0-9]{9})/order/$',
    OrderFormView.as_view(success_url=settings.DEFAULT_SUCCESS_URL),
    name='zoneclient-order'),
```

So far, that technic didn't work, because of the following error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' and 'dict'
```

In fact, I would like the `success_url` to be

```
  # Dashboard
  url(r'^(?P<clientcode>[0-9]{9})/dashboard/', login_required(
      DashboardView.as_view()), name='zoneclient-dashboard'),
```

How could I modify the top code to work well with `r'^(?P<clientcode>[0-9]{9})/dashboard/'`?

**P.S.** Be aware that I am working with Django 1.7 and DEFAULT_SUCCESS_URL is used more than once.

### UPDATE

```
class OrderFormView(CustomerViewMixin, CreateView, SendTextEmailMixin):
    template_name = 'zoneclient/order-form.html'
    form_class = OrderForm

    email_subject_template = 'zoneclient/emails/order_form_subject.txt'
    email_body_template = 'zoneclient/emails/order_form_body.txt'
    email_recipients = settings.EMAIL_NOTIFY_ORDERS

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.get_customer()
        return form_class(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.send_email()
        log.info('%s\' order #%d was successufully processed.' % (\
            usr(self.request), self.object.id))
        messages.success(
            self.request,
            _('Your order has been placed, thank you!'),
            fail_silently=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_email_context(self):
        context = super(OrderFormView, self).get_email_context()
        context['user'] = self.get_customer()
        context['object'] = self.object
        return context
```

Comment: @phd Two questions: What are you smoking? Can I have some?

Comment: @gitblame Do you have a recommendation for that question?

Comment: success url should resolve to a string. In your example, it doesn't.

Comment: If you could make a full answer, I will accept it. How could I convert it to a string?

Comment: You shouldn't clutter `url` when you have defined a corresponding view anyways. You can override `get_success_url` in view class. It'll consolidate view logic at one place and make debugging easier.

Comment: It's been a month now I am working with django and two months with python. I think I could appreciate a full answer with a little more details.

Comment: I think I provided enough info to build a solution on. Anways, I've added a very basic example in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to overrride `get_success_url()`. You haven't provided implementation of view class, so I've assumed it to be a standard `FormView`.

```
 class OrderFormView(FormView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # form handling logic
        super(OrderFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        clientcode = self.kwargs['clientcode']
        url = '/' + clientcode + '/dashboard/'
        return url
```

You can refer to Django docs for details.

Comment: Are you sure it is compatible with django 1.7? Could you adapt it with my class?  I updated my question few minutes ago.

Comment: Do I need to get rid of `HttpResponseRedirect`?

Comment: Yes, [`get_sucess_url` is there in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url).

Comment: Ok, I got it now.